# Symbol of a partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a series of subsets that form a set however each subset is actually a partition.  Currently I use the conventional subset symbol when writing the appropriate notation and then note the subsets are partitions in the following (or preceding) text.  However, it would be good to have a symbol that refers to a partition naturally just like any other set theory notion. Yet, despite looking in various sources and I haven't come across anything so far. So is there a conventionally accepted maths notation/symbol for a partition? Personally have no problem allocating a suitable symbol if none currently exists but I don't want to 'reinvent the wheel' if I can avoid it.

Comment: Maybe write $\dot\bigcup_i X_i=M$ do indicate that the $X_i$ partition $M$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117715/notation-of-partition

Comment: Each subset is a partition? Or the collection of subsets is a partition?

Comment: Each subset is a partition of the parent set

Comment: it would be good if you provide an example of what you want to write using the symbols that you know. Can you?

Comment: In a basic example, I have $s_i\subset S$.  All I am really after is a symbol that can replace/modify the subset symbol ($\subset$) with one that essentially means "all the subsets contained within S are partitions"

Comment: @MurrayB if you don't use the syntax "@ username" the intended reader is not notified. Anyway, "all the subsets contained within $S$ are partitions" of what?

Comment: @trying - Ok, let's say we have a set, $S$ that consists of balls. Lets make it 100 balls as a nice round number. Now each ball is randomly coloured in one colour of the rainbow. If we let each of the colours be a subset of $S$, which we denote as $s_i$ where $i$ is the index of colours. Now of course $s_i\subset S$ is true but it does not provide the information that the subsets are also partitions (as a colour cannot be present in two subsets). Having a partition notation/symbol would provide more information in the notation without having to make a repeating comment in the text.

Comment: @MurrayB I'm going to post an answer based on this your latest comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't want to overload your text with long notations, you can *define* your *own* notations.

For instance

> Let ${\mathbf{Part}}(X)$ be the set of partitions of $X$.

And later,

> Let $(X_i)_{i\in I} \in \mathbf{Part}(X)$

Comment: The empty set can be one of the sets of a partition?

Comment: Thanks Lærne, I will take your advice and identify a suitable notation for this. Kind of strange, however, that with all the notation there is, a symbol of a partition has not been allocated yet.

Answer (score 1):

If $(P_i)_{i \in I}$ is a partition of a set $Q$ you can write

$\dot\bigcup_{i \in I} P_i=Q$ to denote

$\bigcup_{i \in I} P_i=Q$ and $P_i \cap P_j= \emptyset$ for $i,j \in I$ with $i \ne j$.

Comment: Some P_i is allowed to be empty?

Comment: No. That is included in the definition of "partition".

Comment: By that definition both {{1}}  and { empty set, {1} } are partitions of {1}.

Comment: ???? I said, that according to the definition of "partition": if $(P_i)_{i \in I}$ is a partition of $Q$, then $P_i \ne \emptyset$ for all $i \in I$.

Answer (score 0):

I use
 P partition S
for
P is a pairwise disjoint collection of non-empty subsets of S whose union is P.

Answer (score 0):

> Any collection $\mathcal{A}$ of partitions of $X$ are such that
> $$\mathcal{A}\subset\{X/{\sim}:\forall {\sim}\}$$

where it is understood that $\sim$ are equivalence relations on $X$.

Alternatively, see next.

Any map $f\colon X\to Y$ defines a partition of its domain in *fibers*, a fiber of $y\in Y$ under $f$ being $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. (A fiber is also known as *inverse image* of a singleton or *level set*). The equivalence relation associated to the partition in fibers of a map $f$ is called *kernel of $f$*, indicated by $\ker f$ or by $=_f$, that is, $\forall x_1,x_2\in X$
$$x_1=_fx_2\iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$ and the partition in fibers is indicated by $$X/{=_f}$$

Let's focus our attention on $X^X$, the set of *endofunctions* on $X$.
It is clear that $\{X/{=_f}:f\in X^X\}$ is the set of all the partitions of $X$. (Indeed given any partition of $X$, $\exists f\in X^X$ that is the forward composition of the natural projection of $X$ on the partition with a choice map for the partition.)

> So you don't need to devise a new symbol in place of "$\subset$", because you have that any subset
> $$\mathcal{A}\subset \{X/{=_f}:f\in X^X\}$$
> is a collection of some partitions of $X$.

N.B. restriction to $X^X$ (instead of considering $X^Y$, $\forall Y$) has been chosen to reduce notation complexity, but it not essential.

Comment: with all due respect you are over thinking the question. I just want to know if there is a conventionally used symbol that denotes a partition. Given the various replies to the question I can safely assume that there is no such symbol, hence I have taken Larne's reply that I should identify a suitable symbol and define it to be the notation that refers to a partiton. Simple.

Comment: Thanks, but don't mind. No overthinking from me. I like questions about notation anyway. This is an answer I gave before I read your comment, that changed things a little.

Answer (score -1):

You say in a comment to your question:
"Ok, let's say we have a set, $S$ that consists of balls. Lets make it 100 balls as a nice round number. Now each ball is randomly coloured in one colour of the rainbow. If we let each of the colours be a subset of $S$, which we denote as $s_i$ where $i$ is the index of colours. Now of course $s_i\subset S$ is true but it does not provide the information that the subsets are also partitions (as a colour cannot be present in two subsets). Having a partition notation/symbol would provide more information in the notation without having to make a repeating comment in the text"

**Let's rephrase your example**

Let $S$ and $I$ be sets (whose elements we call *balls* and *colours*, respectively). Let $f\colon S\to I$ be a map (that we call *colour of a ball of $S$*).

You want to know whether there is any standard symbol to represent

> a subset of $S$ whose balls are all and only the balls of $S$ of a given colour

or abstractly,

> a subset of $S$ whose elements are all and only the elements of $S$ having the same value under $f$

because the set-inclusion symbol encodes only the first part of this statement:

> a subset of $S$

In standard symbol it becomes:

$$\{b\in S|f(b)=i\}$$

that is, by definition

> $$f^{-1}(i)$$

or a little more properly $f^{-1}(\{i\})$. It has also a name: the *fiber* (or *level set* or *inverse image* or *preimage*) of $i$ under $f$.

If you want but it is not essential you can write $f^{-1}(i)\subset S$.

You can also see that $\{f(i)|i\in I\}$ is the set of partition of $S$ under $f$, usually written as $S/{=}_f$.

Moreover if you want you can define a map $s\colon I\to S/{=}_f$ such that (using index notation, instead of functional notation) $s_i=f^{-1}(i)$. You can now write:

> $$s_i\subset S$$

So you don't need to substitute a new symbol for the set-inclution symbol, but you need only to define once and for all the partition criterion, through the map $s$ or $f$.

Still one more thing. If you meant that instead of $f$ you have a map $g\colon B\to I$, where $B$ is the set of all balls in the universe and $S\subset B$, $g$ is called *colour of a ball* (whereby the previous $f$ is given by $f=g|_S$), your statement becomes in symbols $g|_S^{-1}(i)$ or also:

> $$g^{-1}(i)\cap S$$